# Somehow lost my MENU from my home page- help!

Tags: menus

I am a total newbie to Wordpress (and an "old school" person!)
Somehow though, I managed to begin to set up a basic website using  Astra - and all was going well.  Then I messed around, added some plug-ins, got rid of the sidebars,increased the size of the header photo, etc. and before I knew it, my menu was completely gone.  Prior to this, I had had a "three bar" type graphic which when clicked,  brought up the list of pages I had created.  I went back and unactivated the plug-ins I had added, tried re-adding the sidebars, decreased the header photo and text size, etc. - but still have no menu. I was up till 5:50 this morning trying to figure it out, and no joy.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You should ask the theme's support; they can probably help you with that.

Answer (score -1):

Go into Theme, Customize, and there should be a "Menu" choice. Select an existing menu (if still there) or create a new one.

When you change themes, you often have to re-specify the menu again, even if it already exists.

The 'three-bar graphic' (AKA "hamburger") is shown at certain (usually smaller) screen sizes. That is a function of how the theme does the CSS for smaller screens. Most will have CSS code that will turn a horizontal text menu into a Hamburger icon that you have to tap to see the menu choices.

It could be that you changes some CSS (in Theme, Customization, Additional CSS) for the CSS class used by the menu that caused it not to display the Hamburger icon. Or you could have deleted/de-specified the menu in the Customization, Menu area.

YOu didn't specify whether you had changed the theme code. Not a good idea, BTW. If you want to re-code parts of the theme, then Child Themes are the way to go. You'll find lots of info in the Codex/Developer area (https://developer.wordpress.org ), along with lots of googles/bings/ducks on Child Themes.